# std::vector of OpenCV points, no push_back method

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, vector

DISCLAIMER: The error threw because `touchesY` was an attribute of a nested class that inherited from cv::ParallelLoopBody which is a const class, which is not shown in this post. The workaround is detailed in the answers.

I have this std::vector of cv::Points3i, but I get an error whenever I try to push_back a new value, which is that there's no "push_back method".

Declared in header file:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3_<int>> touchesY;
```

Call in source file:

```
touchesY.push_back(cv::Point3_<int>(i/mask.step[0],0,i-x));
```

I've included the vector library and I get no error doing this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
```

Could someone point me toward what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Error is: No matching member function for call to 'push_back'.

---

As suggested by @FirstStep, I broke down the code into:

```
cv::Point3_<int> temp(i/mask.step[0],0,i-x);
touchesY.push_back(temp);
```

I now get an error on the first line, saying: No matching constructor for initialization of `'std::vector<cv::Point3_<int>>'`.

---

Full error message:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:687:36:
>   Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
>   std::vector >', but method is not marked const
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:685:36:
>   Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
>   std::vector >', but method is not marked const

Comment: Please copy the actual error.

Comment: Try to break it down. What happens if you write it this way: `cv::Point3_<int> temp(i/mas.step[0],0,i-x); touchesY.push_back(temp);` which part pops an error?

Comment: Sorry, I should have given this information. Now added! Thanks!

Comment: The error should tell you which function _signature_ it's trying to call. Or if it doesn't, that's a poor compiler UI. Does `cv::Point_3` define a copy constructor? as required in this case.

Comment: If that is the entire compiler error message then you need a new compiler.  If it is not please post the full error message.

Comment: I've added the complete error description. I'm using Xcode with default C++ compiler.

Comment: You error message mentions `this`.  It appears you are doping this in a class member function.  If that is the case we need to see that as it appears you are in a `const` member function.  Please make a [mcve] and make sure the errors you give us is the exact error output from that [mcve]

Comment: That is wrong implementing of my suggestion. Please read it again. (declare a **Point** and **Not** a vector, then push_back the **Point** to the vector and **Not** a vector to the vector)

Comment: @FirstStep Oh sorry, I did the change and it still throwout the same error.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect that and post the new error and on WHICH part. This was the goal of the suggestion..

Comment: It sounds like the function you are using the vector within is declared `const` and therefore the vector is `const`, so modification (`push_back`) is impossible. Rethink the design.

Comment: @AndyG Exactly, that's what I found out and detailed in an answer to my question. The thing is that I inherit from cv::ParallelLoopBody, which is a const class (I didn't know that). I found a workaround detailed in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error. As pointed out by @NathanOlivier, it is a context-based error.

Basically, I'm defining a nested class that inherits from cv::ParallelLoopBody, which as an attribute of type std::vector of cv::Point named touchesY. Since I'm inheriting from cv::ParallelLoopBody, it is defined as const, which prevents me from calling push_back on it.

I went around this by moving the attribute to the base class, which I then pass a reference to when creating the nested class, which I then use to call push_back on it.

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: `I inherit from cv::ParallelLoopBody, which is a const class` and `Since I'm inheriting from cv::ParallelLoopBody, it is defined as const` You must mean that its methods are `const`, because a base class cannot be 'made' `const` during inheritance. Its _members_ or _methods_ are either `const` or not, and the derived class inherits those qualifications exactly as-is.

Answer (score -3):

Can't you just change this to emplace_back and drop the `cv::Point3_<int>`?

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the stated question, this does answer a better question: what is the best way to add an object to a container using constructor arguments. `emplace_back` is _the_ way and ensures we avoid the unnecessary copy construction that `push_back` would (or might? barring copy elision) require here. You'd need to drop the inner parentheses too, though.

Comment: I get the same error using `emplace_back`. But would using `emplace_back` be better than using `push_back` ? Thanks!

Comment: I was just hoping that they type you were attempting to push_back was the wrong one and by changing to emplace you would get the correct constructor or a different error. But nope. I generally prefer emplace back to push back.

Comment: @Cedric Yes, by allowing construction _in-place_, `emplace_back()` is often more efficient than, and never less efficient than, `push_back()`, which instead requires an already-constructed element to copy in (potential copy elision notwithstanding). So, `emplace_back()` is a preferable default. You can find many good discussions of this on SO.